# R: Plot multiple file formats at once

Tags: r, plot, knitr

Originally I wanted to knit a document and generate *svg* and *png* versions of the plots at the same time.

I checked the documentation of *knitr* and found out that in `opts_chunk$set(dev = ...)` you can set your own function which accepts plots.

But this is also not so easy as the call of `svg(); pdf()` opens both devices but just the last one will generate the output.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you generating HTML output? And if so, is the idea to have the PNG displayed in the HTML and the SVG saved externally?

Comment: Also, are you using RMarkdown? Or knitr by itself?

Comment: `dev=c("png", "svg", "pdf")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are working with RMarkdown, and attempting to have each plot outputted in multiple formats, you can do:

````
---
output:
  html_document:
    self_contained: false
---

```{r}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(dev=c('png', 'svg'))
```

```{r}
plot(rnorm(10), rnorm(10))
```
````

If your file is named "README.Rmd", then the images will be saved to `README_files/figure-html/`.

The `self_contained` [yaml parameter](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html) tells rmarkdown to save images (and other resources such as JavaScript) externally, instead of embedding them directly in the HTML file.

The `dev` option (see [knitr docs](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/)) can simply be passed a vector of all the formats you wish to save the plot as.

Comment: But it is really undocumented, that you can pass a vector, or am I blind?

Comment: @Jakob it's there - buried in the documentation for `dev` in the [chunk options](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/#chunk_options) section of the knitr docs. Easy to overlook though ;)